# ROR link_to method problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass some values through a link and I want them to be invisible. These are the options I've tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', :controller => :comments, :action => :new, :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id, :method => :post %>

<%= link_to 'Add comment',{ :controller => :comments, :action => :new, :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id}, :method => :post %>

<%= link_to 'Add comment', :controller => :comments, :action => :new, :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id, %>

<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_comment_path, :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id, :method => :post %>
```

First option - treats method as a parameter:
http://localhost:2000/comments/new?idea_id=1&method=post&user_id=1

Second option - goes like this: http://localhost:2000/comments/new?idea_id=1&user_id=1 
and also causes routing error: "Routing Error No route matches "/comments/new"

Third option - loads the form, but of course is like: http://localhost:2000/comments/new?idea_id=1&user_id=1

Fourth option - looks good (http://localhost:2000/comments/new) but the same routing error like the second one.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS

I was asked to give my routes, so here they are:

```
  resources :rights

  resources :comments

  resources :ideas

  resources :users

  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root :to => 'main#home'

  #match '/comments/new' => "comments#new" # this doesn't help

  match '/home', :to => 'main#home'
  match '/contact', :to => 'main#contact'
  match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'
  match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: What do you mean by 'invisible'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have RESTful routes

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_comment_path, 
            :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id, :method => :post %>
```

should be

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', comments_path, 
            :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id, :method => :post %>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. comments_path refers to the index of files, while new_comment_path refers to comments/new.

Comment: GET `comments_path` refers to index however POST `comments_path` refers to `create` action

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it sounds like you have a problem in your routes file. Either check if you have the `resource :comments` defined or post your routes file here and we'll help you out. It's possible that it's not working because you are trying to POST...

If you want 'invisible' variables (I assume you mean that you do not want the variables to appear in the URL), you'll have to *POST* to the page rather than just link to it. In this case, your second example is the best bet. It goes against convention to POST to /new so that could be what is causing the 'no routes' error if you're using `resource :comments`

Give this a try in your routes.rb:

```
match '/comments/new' => "comments#new"
```

Give that a try, it should load the correct page and give you access to the variables you passed through to it through `params`.

Please note, that this goes wildly against convention. Is there a reason why you don't want those variables to appear in the URL? It's likely there's a better way of doing what you're thinking and if you explain we can advise you as best as we can.

Comment: I have resource :comments in my routes. And yes you're right this POST causes the routing error.

Comment: Adding match '/comments/new' => "comments#new" to my routes resolved the routing error, but parameters didn't pass.

Comment: What I want to do is to modify comment creation (generated with scaffold) so that it has information who is the author and what's being commented. There is an Idea. Beneath anybody can add comments. So user_id and idea_id should be passed from Idea show view to comment new action. And I think it's not professional to pass values like ids explicitly. So do you have any ideas how to do this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly defined the routes?
Can you show how they are?
You should have something like this for that to work: `resource :comments`

Also, in general /new works with a GET, and a POST is sent when creating...

Comment: But I need to pass 2 values to a 'new' action implicitly form a 'show' view of another model.

Answer (score 0):

The method is part of html_options, you need to separate the two hashes like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', {:controller => :comments, :action => :new, :idea_id => @idea.id, :user_id => @idea.user.id}, :method => :post %>
```

Comment: This causes routing error. I suppose because I try to force post method for get action

Comment: I see the issue. You're trying to create a new resource via POST to the /comment/new, but that route is only valid for GET requests. You can certainly pass parameters but they will be GET parameters as you've discovered. To "hide" the parameters, you need a POST but your only route that uses POST to create a new resource is new_comments_path(). @bohdan's answer is the correct one.